# Unity Online Interpolation Lerp Flickering 2D Gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, synchronization, interpolation, multiplayer, flicker

I'm trying to get my basic game online and got into some problems.
I followed [this tutorial](http://www.paladinstudios.com/2013/07/10/how-to-create-an-online-multiplayer-game-with-unity/) which is really nice and everything worked but one thing, the interpolation.

Without interpolation, I have too much latency issues (the other player is "lagging" a lot). I tried to follow the tutorial, adding

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (networkView.isMine)
    else{
        syncTime += Time.deltaTime;
        rigidbody2D.position = Vector3.Lerp(syncStartPosition, syncEndPosition, syncTime / syncDelay);
    }
```

And using this method:

```
void OnSerializeNetworkView(BitStream stream, NetworkMessageInfo info)
{
    Vector3 syncPosition = Vector3.zero;
    if (stream.isWriting)
    {
        syncPosition = rigidbody2D.position;
        stream.Serialize(ref syncPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        stream.Serialize(ref syncPosition);

        syncTime = 0f;
        syncDelay = Time.time - lastSynchronizationTime;
        lastSynchronizationTime = Time.time;

        syncStartPosition = rigidbody2D.position;
        syncEndPosition = syncPosition;
    }
}
```

But now the other player is invisible when not moving, and is visible but flickering a lot when moving (flickering so much I hardly see it). Since my method is called from FixedUpdate, I am wondering if the gameobject is simple refreshing so much that I don't even see it. Is that possible?

In any case, would you have an idea on how to fix this?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

PS: I tried to lerp only if syncTime/syncDelay < 1.0 to be sure I don't extrapolate, but it did not change a thing.

PPS: When I use the interpolation, it flickers a lot but I can see that the position is right, it is not lagging like before, so the best would be to resolve how to make my interpolation and not removing it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use Time.deltaTime in FixedUpdate(). FixedUpdate() is for physics only and actually runs around 50fps. On the other hand Time.deltaTime is the time for the last frame. So, technically you will get flickering in your lerp function. Use the function in Update(). And I can see, you are just transforming positions. So, why rigidbody2D.position? you can use transform.position and move the whole codes to Update(). Hope it will help.

Comment: I tried to put the lerp interpolation in Update() but it did change a thing. Using transform or rigibody2D changed nothing as well. Thanks anyway.